# Gain crossover frequency in bode plot for control system

Tags: control-system, bode-plot, frequency-response, phase-margin

I know that gain crossover frequency (freq at which gain is 0dB) is where the phase margin is calculated. I also know that the gain crossover freq must be lower than phase crossover freq for stable system.

However, in loop shaping, I don't know **what should be the ideal gain crossover frequency?**. For context, if I draw the bode plot of the open loop transfer function, P(s)C(s), of a control system, where P(s) is some first order unstable plant and C(s) is a PI control that stabilizes it, the plot will look something like:

[image]

Notice that the gain plot is pretty much a straight line. So if I was to make a guess, the gain crossover freq should be the average (middle value) of the usually low disturbance freq and the usually high sensor's noise freq. Considering:

1. For disturbance rejection, you want the sensitivity function gain to be low at low freq
2. For sensor's noise rejection, you want the complementary function gain to be low at high freq.

Is this guess correct?

Edit:
The phase plot would not actually look like that, the image is just used to illustrate where the gain crossover freq is.

Comment: I'm interested. Can you give an example of a first order unstable plant?

Comment: I don't really want to give a specific example because I want to know what should the crossover freq be in general. To be honest, I dont think it matters what the plant system is as long as it is 1st order, or even 2nd order in the [general form](https://img.brainkart.com/imagebk7/UeP7G9j.jpg) and the control is of the form PID, then the resulting bode **gain** plot will more or less look like the image above (straight line).